# Multiple Warehouse - WooCommerce & Table Rate Shipping Plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I currently have two warehouses (one on the east coast and west coast of USA). The problem I am trying to solve is finding the optimal method of shipping based on the user's shipping address and our two warehouses. It is unwise for us to ship a product from the west coast all the way over to a consumer on the east coast and vice versa.

We currently run WooCommerce and have the Table Rate Shipping plugin installed. I've created two zones (one for west and one for east) to divide our two shipping areas and I understand you can create a shipping class for each WooCommerce product but you are unable to create more than one under a product. If this was possible, I was thinking of creating two shipping classes under each product and finding an optimal shipping method that way.

I believe there is TradeGecko but it is a costly service that provides much more functionality than what I technically need. Does anyone here know of an ideal solution to optimally ship our products from two warehouses? Help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you just look at what state the address is in? Divide the United States into 2 halves. The west half you use the west warehouse, and the east half you ship with the east one. Put those states into a list/database and store which warehouse to ship from for each state.

Comment: Is it that easy? Wouldn't I need something such as google maps API to check each user's input and then find the state or no?

Comment: Most likely, when a user inputs their personal shipping address, they don't enter it as a single string. There would be fields for "address", "state", and "zipcode", all separate. I don't know anything about WooCommerce, bu you should already know what state each customer is from, simply by accessing that information. You shouldn't need Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is for US try using a flat shipping rate (Not sure if its possible for you, but I dont think there should be much price difference within US ). You can use this plugin "Flat Rate per State/Country/Region for WooCommerce", it allows you to set different regions and states and then set prices for those regions. So for instance if someone from east cost orders a product you can send it for flat $5, similar can be done for West cost. I dont know how your workflow is but the relevant warehouse should be automatically notified when the product is booked. while for the rest of the world the pricing should remain standard.

Comment: This seems similar to my plugin Table Rate Shipping. It has the same functionality but my issue is with two warehouses and finding where to ship it. I believe Table Rate and Flat Shipping default with one warehouse.

Comment: So you mean you just need to notify the relevant warehouse about the order? If this is the case then there definitely will be hooks from the plugin you are using, that will tell you which region the order came from eg East cost/ West cost, and then depending on this you can send an email to the relavant warehouse.